# webapp2 and mod_wsgi serving Content-Type: image/jpeg

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, content-type, webapp2

I have a `webapp2.RequestHandler` that gets images like so:

```
class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # do some stuff to magically choose an image
        # i'm going to omit that because it's not relevant to the question
        img = ...
        self.response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
        self.response.write(img)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/image', ImageHandler)], debug=True)

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It all works hunky dory; I go to the url, I see an image. But I added the following to run it thru mod_wsgi:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    resp = app.get_response(environ['PATH_INFO'])
    start_response(resp.status, resp.headerlist)
    yield resp.body
```

And I get a `500 Internal Server Error` with the following in the logs:

```
[Thu Dec 19 14:25:57 2013] [error] [client 172.16.18.37] mod_wsgi (pid=32457): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/data/www/wsgi/main.py'.
[Thu Dec 19 14:25:57 2013] [error] [client 172.16.18.37] TypeError: expected byte string object for header value, value of type unicode found
```

If I load up the img the same way in the interpreter, it is not a unicode string:

```
>>> img.__class__
<type 'str'>
>>> import webapp2
>>> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/fake', webapp2.RequestHandler)])
>>> resp = app.get_response('/fake')
>>> resp.write(img)
>>> resp.body.__class__
<type 'str'>
```

All the above works for a separate `RequestHandler` with `Content-Type: text/html` and a simple text response. What's happening here? How can I force a byte string (in python 2.7.4)?

Comment: The error is complaining about a header value, not the body. Can you try to log/dump/... `resp.headerlist` in your WSGI application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sk1p, the wonderful commenter above, pointed out my issue is not with the response body, but with one of the headers:

```
>>> import main
>>> resp = main.app.get_response('/image')
>>> resp.headerlist
[('Content-Type', u'image/jpg; charset=utf-8'), ('Content-Length', '4369913'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')]
```

`Content-Type` was unicode...

Comment: The WSGI specification is adhered to quite strictly by mod_wsgi. Other WSGI servers, especially pure Python implementations are quite sloppy and can allow some things which are actually in violation of the WSGI specification. Such pure Python WSGI servers can be a pain when you want to write code which is actually portable across WSGI server implementations.